# Why is subspace of solutions of linear ODE n dim?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we are considering homogeneous linear ordinary differential equations among differentiable real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. equations of the form $\mathrm{D} f =0$, then why is the subspace of solutions $n$-dimensional, where $n$ is the largest integer such that the differential operator $\mathrm{D}$ contains a derivative of degree $n$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change of variables $y_1=f,y_2=f', \dots,y_n=f^{(n-1)}$ brings the $n$-dimensional single equation $Df=0$ into a linear $n \times n$ system. Using the existence and uniqueness theorem you can construct $n$ solutions $\mathbf{y}_1,\mathbf{y}_2, \dots, \mathbf{y}_n$ with initial conditions $\mathbf{y_i}(x_0)=\mathbf{e}_i=\text{i'th column of identity}$. It is obvious that the solutions $\{\mathbf{y}_1, \dots, \mathbf{y}_n \}$ are linearly independent, and also that any solution to the system, $\mathbf{y}$, with an arbitrary initial condition $\mathbf{y}(x_0)=\mathbf{v}$ can be written as linear combination of the $\mathbf{y}_i$'s.

Comment: I do not understand your first sentence.  Can you please be more explicit?

Comment: @DanDouglas He meant that we can make a coupled system of first-order ODE instead of higher-order ODE by mentioned change of variables; it is known that these two tasks are equivalent. I'll just add that (since it is obvious that solution space of homogeneous linear ODE is a vector space) finding the system of linearly independent vectors that span all vector space solves the question of dimension instantly.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, Evgeny!  It was helpful.