# The set of all solution of $n$-th ordinary differential equation is basis of dimension $n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that the set of solution of $n^\text{th}$ order homogeneous differential equation is subspace with dimension $n$.

**What I'm doing**

let $S=\{y:L(y)=0\}$ where $L(y)=y^{(n)}+a_1y^{(n-1)}+.....a_ny$

then $S$ is subspace of set of all $n-$ times  differential function?

[I proved this $S$ subspace as $ay_1+by_2 \in S$ as if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are two solutions ]

and how to prove this subspace has dimension $n$?

Comment: Are your coefficients $a_{k}$ constant?

Comment: @in_mathematica_we_trust....these are function in $x$

Comment: Sorry, can't help then.

Comment: @in_mathematica_we_trust.....what if these are constants

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44853/simplest-proof-of-dimension-of-solution-space-for-linear-odes/44916

Second answer.

Comment: @InverseProblem I hope https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461455/why-is-subspace-of-solutions-of-linear-ode-n-dim will be of some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Question about the solution of the differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898267/a-question-about-the-solution-of-the-differential-equation)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question several times in the hope of getting an answer, this is not accepted here.