# Will an nth order differential equation have n arbitrary constants?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently watched a video about differential equations and this phrase was used:

‘A first order differential equation will have a solution with one arbitrary constant, C, this is called a general solution’.

My question is whether this is true in general, so:

will a first order differential equation always have exactly one arbitrary constant?

Will, for example, a third order differential equation have exactly three arbitrary constants?

Comment: "only" True for linear ordinary  differential equations.

Comment: What do you mean by "general equation"? Do you mean "general solution"? I think that this notation is more or less only used for linear ODEs. Also a linear ODE of $n$-th order won't have $n$ arbitrary constants, but the general solution will have.

Comment: The space of solutions of an $n$-th order linear ODE is $n$-dimensional. See, for instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461455/why-is-subspace-of-solutions-of-linear-ode-n-dim

Comment: Why don't you ask at youtube?