# Question for homogeneous linear ode with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the problem $$y'''-3y''+4y=0$$ I know the fact any linear combination of $\{e^{-t},e^{2t},xe^{2t}\}$ are solution for above and the solution set should be vector space because solution set is linearly closed.

However,I don't know how to verify the solution space has 3 dimension.

> Please let me know if you know the any theorem or book or proof about this fact.

Comment: Show that $\{e^{-t},e^{2t},te^{2t}\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: My edit: please don't shout, avoid whole sentences in uppercase, there are other means to highlight.

Comment: I know the fact $\{e^{-t},e^{2t},te^{2t}\}$ are linearly independent. But I don't know this set span the solution set. (I.e every solution is represented by of linear combination of above set.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution space of a homogeneous linear differential equation of order $n$ always has dimension $n$ because the $n$ initial conditions uniquely specify the solution. Now if you have found three linearly independent elements of that three-dimensional solution space they must necessarily span the whole space.
If the first statement is unclear as it stands, here it is explained in more detail: [Why is subspace of solutions of linear ODE n dim?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461455/why-is-subspace-of-solutions-of-linear-ode-n-dim)

Comment: Thank you I understand what you mean!